# jQuery .val() doesn´t make a 'change'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, testing

I have problems testing my JavaScript. A part of my test looks like

```
$('#activityType').val("33");
$('#favorite').click();
```

The `$('#activityType')` is a select field and I want to select the option with value "33". Now I expected, that this would be a change, so that my function in my program like

```
$('body').on('change', '.item-select', function() {
    var itemRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    changeBookableItemInputFields(itemRow);
});
```

will be executed.

The `$('#activityType')` has got the class-attribute `item-select`, so I don´t understand, why `$('#activityType').val("33");` is no change. I changed the value and the css-attribute is there. The body should be able to find it and the function should be executed.

Can anybody tell me, why it doesn´t work?

Comment: Changing an element value programmatically does **not** trigger the "change" event. You can do that explicitly yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing a value with JavaScript does not trigger the events, you need to manually fire it. jQuery makes that easy with [`.trigger(eventName)`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#activityType').val("33").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for calling any event using program.

`change` event is for user types into the input.

You can manually call the any event event using after setting the value:

```
$('#activityType').trigger("change");
```